# Integrate wordpress in sharepoint server

Tags: wordpress, sharepoint

I want to build a website using SharePoint server 2013  as Software architecture , Can I integrate WordPress inside SharePoint server ?

Answer (score 1):

If by integrate you mean run on the same (SharePoint) server, there are a few options. Sorry if this is obvious, but SharePoint runs on Windows Server/IIS, while WordPress traditionally runs on Apache. So, you might be able to use something like [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) or install directly into IIS using [Web PI](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_on_Microsoft#Prerequisites), but it will likely get messy.

I would either use SharePoint's built-in blogging functionality, or host the WordPress site elsewhere and try to integrate posts using an approach like [this](http://netwovenblogs.com/2013/11/21/integrating-wordpress-blog-into-sharepoint-2013/).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run WordPress on the same server as Share Point.  Share Point is IIS, and WordPress runs quite well on that.
I develop in IIS, and live sites tend to be LAMP.  This way I know the site is agnostic about the platform it's on.  I've been doing this for years and have run into few issues.  There's a few minor gotcha's but no real show stoppers.

For more on setting up WordPress in IIS, see: https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_on_Microsoft_IIS